# Getting space instead of + during filter,

Tags: filter, angular2-forms

I am trying to apply filter for email, whenever I am trying to filter and pass "+" (plus sign) as an argument in angular 2, It passes whitespace instead of that. Why so? I tried using EncodedURI but It didnt worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLEncoded should be true in order to do that. 
try `UrlEncoded:true`